# How to understand an _asm command in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am picking up someone else's C++ code in MS Visual Studio and have encountered the line:

```
 if (l > n) _asm{int 3};
```

I understand that is is meant to break to the debugger.  I also understand that it's deprecated and has been replaced with:

```
__debugbreak()
```

My question is... how does this work?  Why should such an inline assembler command result in the debugger?

Comment: [Read the section on INT3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29#INT3)

Comment: For future posts, it is a good idea to include the target OS/Hardware whenever posting assembly language related questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same thing as setting a breakpoint with the IDE, but the difference is that with the IDE or any other debugger, it sets a breakpoint overwriting the chosen opcode with `int 3` and with `__asm { int 3 }`, it sets as a new opcode line.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comment, int 3 is an assembly instruction that triggers a hardware interrupt, which causes the running thread  ( your code ) to halt while the operating system services that interrupt.  Not sure of the specifics, but the debugger must be able to hook into the os to get a notification of that interrupt, and act appropriately.

Read more: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kangsu/2005/09/07/no-more-int-3/